# Loading resource from a jar in a Web Application

Tags: java, resources, jar, classloader

I read all the questions with answers but still it doesn't work for me.

In my web application I have a jar which contains few images and xmls. These are required by the classes in that jar itself. So I modified the required lines as below:

I changed the classes inside my jar to refer the resources(which are present inside the jar itself) by using :

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(path) // returns null
```

I had also tried before :

```
MyClassName.class.getResource(path) // null again
```

I read a lot about this and got to know that the later line of code will be able to pick up the resources, but unfortunately neither of it works for me...am I missing something?

Note: Running on Tomcat7 and since I am running on Vista, I get the 'path' value as '\myFolder\images\'

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact path value you're using and whats the location of your resource file or files?

Comment: the path is picked from another config.xml in the jar(which is read perfectly) .. path given in the xml is '/alpha/images' i.e.

MyJar.jar
 |
 |
 ___ alpha
      |
      |
      ____images

but changes to \alpha\images because of windows(I guess that is the only reason?)

Comment: Can you give the exact path value that you're passing to the getResource method? It needs to be different depending on whether you're using the class loader or class method to find the resource. The path for the "class" version (which I'd recommend) should be something like "images/myImage.gif". This assumes your image is in an images subfolder of the current class's package folder, and the image file is called myImage.gif.

Comment: Thanks for the info. After much digging I figured it out. Answering it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few points one must take care when loading resources from within a jar, which is embedded in a web application

1. Loading a file is different than loading a resource. When we use `File.seperator` it is usually w.r.t Files and absolute paths. It is not recommended for loading resources.
2. When loading resources from within a jar, make sure you are not using the `File.seperator`  and using the normal '/' as it is relative path w.r.t the jar.
3. If you are reading properties from an xml within the jar...and that property refers to another location, make sure you are reading it with the '/' slashes. Again, `File.seperator` will not work for loading resources because it will replace '/' with '\' (windows system)
4. Finally, when loading resources in your jar code, use the following lines

   MyCurrentClass.class.getResource(path)

Hope it helps people dealing with xmls within jars in a web application